# Spring Boot different environments

Tags: spring-boot, deployment, properties, production-environment, maven-profiles

I have a spring boot application, but the development environment has a different configuration from the production one (example: MySQL password).
I would like to be able to distinguish the properties files, so that I can compile once and be able to launch the application both locally and in production, specifying the profile for the environment.
How can I do this thing?

Answer (score 2):

Define properties that are the same in all environments in `application.properties`. For properties that are only specified to a particular environment , define them in their profile specific properties file such as `application-prod.properties` or `application-dev.properties`. `prod` and `dev` are the profile name that you can freely define as you like.

Profile specific properties will override `application.properties`.

To enable a particular profile , you can specify it through the JVM system property `spring.profiles.active` likes :

```
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod app.jar
```

Or through OS environment variable :

```
export SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.profile-specific) and [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.properties-and-configuration.set-active-spring-profiles) for details